# SQL Server 2012 - Using LAG to get data off previous rows

Tags: sql-server-2012, lag

I've been able to use LAG to get data from a previous row but I'm struggling to use it to resolve a more complicated problem.

Essentially for each episode in my table there might be, say, 10 unique attendances.  Each attendance has a value of 1, 2 or 3.

What I need to accomplish is when an attendance value increases all of the following rows must have the same value.

e.g.

```
Episode Attendance Value  New Value
 12345      1        1        1
 12345      2        1        1
 12345      3        2        2
 12345      4        1        2
 12345      5        1        2
 12345      6        2        2
 12345      7        3        3
 12345      8        1        3
 12345      9        1        3
 12345      10       1        3
 34567      1        1        1
 34567      2        2        2
 34567      3        1        2
 34567      4        2        2
 34567      5        1        2
 34567      6        3        3
 34567      7        1        3
 56789      1        2        2
 56789      2        1        2
 56789      3        1        2
```

So the new value can increase from a 1 to a 2 or 3 and from a 2 to a 3, but it shouldn't ever decrease.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Using LAG might not be the right answer but I'm a bit of a novice as you might have gathered.

Here's the SQL I've got so far:

```
    SELECT *,


NewValue = 
CASE    WHEN EPISODEID = Lag(EpisodeID,1) OVER(ORDER BY EpisodeID Asc) AND
 LAG(Value, 1) OVER(ORDER BY [EpisodeID] asc, Attendance) >= Value THEN LAG(Value,1)
 OVER(ORDER BY [EpisodeID] asc, Attendance)

        ELSE        Value
        END 
FROM TABLE
```

It only works for one row and I can see why, but I haven't found enough guidance to improve on it.

Frustratingly, I could do this in Excel but I'm trying to improve my SQL skills

Comment: Just realised that it hasn't left the table formatting in my table example - how would I get it to show correctly?

Comment: Attendances in our system are coded level 1, 2 or 3 and I've been asked to count how many level 2 and 3 attendances there are.  Simple.  However in an episode if an attendance is at a higher level then all following attendances should be counted at that new level.  The previous ones stay the same.  So attendance values in the order 1,1,1,2,1,1,3 would become 1,1,1,2,2,2,3.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried so far.  Otherwise, your question just looks like "do my homework for me" and people are less likely to answer.

Comment: thanks Toby - edited with my stab at the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a CTE to solve the problem.  The CTE checks for what row the counter should increase for each episode group and attendance event.  It then joins on to your table and assigns the max value that attendance event should have based on your episode.

```
    ;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT episode
        , value
        , MIN(attendance) AS row_counter

    FROM [your_table]

    GROUP BY episode
        , value
    )

SELECT t.episode
    , t.attendance
    , t.value
    , MAX(cte.value) AS new_Val

FROM [your_table] t

LEFT JOIN CTE
    ON cte.episode = t.episode
        AND t.attendance >= cte.row_counter

WHERE cte.episode = t.episode

GROUP BY t.episode
    , t.attendance
        , t.value

ORDER BY t.episode
    , t.attendance
```

Comment: This is the answer - can't thank you enough dfundako! Exactly what I needed.